# Applying a % style binding with knockout via function not working

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I want to set the width of a div equal to a percentage calculated by a javascript method.  I can get knockout to apply the style binding properly using this:

```
<div class="bar" data-bind="style: { width: '50%'}"></div>
```

but when I try to use a function to generate the output, it breaks:

```
<div class="bar" data-bind="style: { width: function(){return '50' + '%';}}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Was hoping to see a percentage example from the knockout.js docs but didn't see one anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out you can get it to work with an anonymous function, you just need to explicitly call that function:

```
<div data-bind="style: { width: function(){ return '50%'; }() }"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it won't take an anonymous function, but if you define the function as a named, method, I got it to work.

```
<script>
calcWidth = function(amt) {
  return amt + '%';
}
</script>

<div class="bar" data-bind="style: { width: calcWidth(50)}"></div>
```

**Note:**
I only found this out by trial and error on knockout's interactive tutorial. I'm not sure if there are other factors that come into play here, but this was the best I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 3):

This is working fine:

```
<div data-bind="style: { width: function() + '%' }"></div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/31377/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this that will also be useful if you need to apply multiple styles dynamically and you want a single function to calculate those, you can simply return a string from a function in your view model.

View:

```
<div data-bind="style: $root.calculateStyles() }"></div>
```

ViewModel:

```
self.calculateStyles = function (obj) { 
    // properties could also potentially be written dynamically depending on obj's state
    return { backgroundColor: '#112233', color: 'white', width: '35px' };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-bind="style: { width: WATCHEDPERCENTAGE + '%' }"></div>
```